# Excluding a specific record from a delete query

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have some data like this (date type stuff, month/day/year/flag/user columns)

```
1 - 1 - 2013 flag:1 user:123456
1 - 2 - 2013 flag:0 user:123456
1 - 3 - 2013 flag:0 user:123456
1 - 4 - 2013 flag:0 user:123456
1 - 5 - 2013 flag:1 user:123456
3 - 1 - 2013 flag:1 user:987654
3 - 2 - 2013 flag:0 user:987654
3 - 3 - 2013 flag:0 user:987654
3 - 4 - 2013 flag:0 user:987654
3 - 5 - 2013 flag:1 user:987654
```

I want to delete all the records from the user 123456 except the first one. I tried:

```
DELETE FROM table 
WHERE year = 2013 
AND user = 123456 
AND (month != 1 AND day != 1 AND year != 2013 AND flag != 1)
```

The flag is important. I am stumped on this. I've tried NOT IN like this:

```
DELETE 
FROM table 
WHERE year = 2013 
AND user = 123456 
NOT IN (SELECT * 
        FROM table 
        WHERE month = 1 AND day = 1 AND year = 2013 AND flag = 1)
```

But I can't get NOT IN to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The first one fails because you're looking for year = 2013 as well as year != 2013. The second fails because you're not telling it what shouldn't be in the results. Why are you not storing the date in a date column?

Comment: I'm working heavily with dates, and I've found storing them in 3 columns makes it easier for me to deal with them. It's probably less efficient?

Comment: You can go YEAR(datefield) and MONTH(datefield) and DAY(datefield) to isolate the three parts of the date. Lots of really neat stuff for you at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first query fails, because `year = 2013` and `year != 2013` is not possible. Try the modified version below.

```
DELETE FROM table 
WHERE year = 2013 
AND user = 123456 
AND NOT (month = 1 AND day = 1 AND year = 2013 AND flag = 1)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. The AND NOT is what I was looking for... worked perfectly!